# ScrollSpy not working on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to add the scrollspy thing in my website but it's not working as of yet. It doesn't highlight the links in the navigation bar when  I'm in that section which is what scrollspy does so I couldn't figure out the problem. I have pasted the code and help me to figure out where it went wrong.

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top" style=" font-family: 'Lobster Two', cursive, serif;font-size:25px">my website</a>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-toggle hidden-md-up float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
            <!-- Navigation Bar List Contents -->
            <div class="clearfix hidden-md-up"></div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav float-md-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#about">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#sample">Sample Article</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#topics">Topics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#whyus">Why Choose Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <a href="form.php" class="btn btn-md btn-info btn-block" role="button">Order now</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

section area

```
   <!-- Start About Us Section -->
        <section id="about">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 text-xs-center">
                        <h2 class="section-heading" style="color: black">About Us</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-lg-12">
                       hello world                   
                   </div>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </section>
        <!--End About Us-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your CSS but I'm guessing you didn't set the `position` of `body` to `relative`.

From [Bootstrap's documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/scrollspy/#requires-relative-positioning):

> No matter the implementation method, scrollspy requires the use of
>   `position: relative`; on the element you’re spying on. In most cases
>   this is the `<body>`. When scrollspying on elements other than the
>   `<body>`, be sure to have a `height` set and `overflow-y: scroll`; applied.

Answer (score 0):

Update your body tag to:

```
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbarResponsive">
```

The reason being that you must target the parent element of a bootstrap .nav component

CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar-example">
  ...
  <div id="navbar-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Reference: [Bootstrap 3 Documentation // Javascript: Scrollspy Usage](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy-usage/%20[Bootstrap%20Documentation%20//%20Scrollspy%20Usage])